# Facebook Messenger open callback

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot

Is there any way to get callback When users open messenger ?

Currently I am developing Facebook chat bot, for existing user on Facebook page
I want to show get started button, that's why i need some callback when user open
messenger

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a callback to have Get Started button. All you need for this is to register the button with your app.

To do so, you send a curl as following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ \
  "get_started":{ \
    "payload":"<GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD>" \
  } \
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

You may change GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD to any text you like - that is what Facebook is going to send to your webhook if the user clicks GET STARTED.

More information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/).